# How to ignore `NaN` values in a pandas dataframe while using `rjust()`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (`df`) with a column (`'ISNN'`). Most of the values in that column are strings of 8 characters (e.g. `"12345678"`). Some of them are smaller (e.g. `"983750"`) and I would like to add a left padding of zeros in order to reach exactly 8 characters (in the previous example, thus obtaining `"00983750"`)

I am using `rjust` as follows and it works as expected:

```
df['ISSN'] = df['ISSN'].apply(lambda x: str(x).rjust(8, '0'))
```

But since some of the values of that column are `NaN`, they get modified as well and I get `00000nan`. How can I apply `rjust()` just to non-`NaN` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pandas' `.str.zfill`, which handles `NaN` for you:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"ISSN":[np.nan, '1234', '12345678']})

df['ISSN'] = df['ISSN'].str.zfill(8)
```

Output:

```
       ISSN
0       NaN
1  00001234
2  12345678
```